# Load plaintext output without write files

Tags: shell-script

I have a program (than I run from terminal) that generates 4 plaintext files.

For example

```
./myprog
```

generates `file1.dat`, `file2.dat`, `file3.dat`, `file4.dat`.

I want to create a script that allows me run `myprog` and load (read) this four "file outputs" but without write the physical files (may be, load that files only in ram). Is this possible?

The reason is that I need about 70000 of this files, so I don't want to lose time saving extra files, I just need to use the information.

=============================================

**Specific example that was asked me in comments**

1. [triangle software](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) (free software to generate meshes for numerical calculus, written in C) read the file `mesh.poly`:

:

```
4 2 0 1
1   0     0     20
2   1     0     20
3   1     1     10
4   0     1     10

4 1
1 1 2   20 # bottom side
2 2 3   20 # right side
3 3 4   10 # top side
4 4 1   20 # left side

0

1
1 0.5 0.5 1 0.0005
```

2. The command`triangle mesh.poly` generate the following files:

`mesh.node`:

```
4  2  0  1
   1    0  0    20
   2    1  0    20
   3    1  1    10
   4    0  1    10
```

and `mesh.ele`

```
2  3  0
   1       4     1     2
   2       2     3     4
```

and other two files, in total: four output files.

3. After generate this files I need to use the information in other program, written by me on fortran, that need the `*.node` and `*.ele` information. I'm thinking to write a `.sh` file to do this automatically, but I can use python or any language that allows me to run executable programs.

To load (read) the `mesh.node` and `mesh.ele` is easy. But I need to generate thousands physical files as output of `triangle` and input of my fortran code. For that reason, **I'm looking for a way to "write virtual files"** thinking that will be more efficient and clean.

**My problem** is that I have about 70000 `mesh.poly` generating 70000x4 output (and little) files.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. Load the files where? What do you mean by "but without write that files"? How can we know what files to load? Will they be the only files in the directory? How exactly should the files be "loaded"?

Comment: We may think that `myprog` is in some folder and generates all its output files in the same folder, and in that folder there is nothing else.

For example: each output file (of `myprog`) has matrices or arrays info (many rows with numbers and words).

The natural way is: first generate the 4 files, and then load (read) all of them. But I'm looking for a way to generate and use the output files without generate the "physical" files. May be theat is not possible.

**My English is not good enough, so I appreciate your questions for my clearer my statement.**

Comment: Please *[edit]* your question to clarify, comments are hard to read and easy to miss. And yes, what you're asking for is possible but we can't help you if you don't show us the relevant parts of your program. Even better, make a minimal example that reproduces the issue and show us that.

Comment: One method might be to mount a memory filesystem and write the output to that, assuming the physical disks are slow, and sufficient memory exists.

Comment: @terdon : I added my specific problem to the question.

Comment: Thanks, that's a little clearer. I think you're looking for either simple pipes (`command1 | command2`) or [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe). However, again, I can't really know since I don't know if the software you are using can take input from stdin or needs an actual file. In either case, one of the two approaches should work. Why don't you try and then edit your question with the results of your attempt.

Comment: @terdon I will study your ideas, that will take me some time. After that I'll tell you how I was :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a a [memory-backed file-system (tmpfs)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmpfs), or [FIFOs (Named Pipes)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe)

Maybe your distribution already does setup a `tmpfs`-backed mountpoint somewhere. You could use that for all the temporary files. (e.g. `/tmp/`on some systems and configurations)

On my system -by default- I get a sufficiently big tmpfs under /run/user/1000, that would do just fine for the <300MiB you specified.

If you are root on the machine, you could mount yourself a new one somewhere, and use that.

Failing that:
As a normal user, you could setup 4 Named Pipes with `mkfifo` and use them as "temporary storage area".

Your algorithm could then be along the following lines of pseudo-code.

```
make_4_fifos_with_mkfifo
foreach polyfile in directory do
  rename_fifos_to_use_given_prefix $polyfile
  run triangle $polyfile
  run fortranCMD polyfile.node $polyfile.ele ...
done
```

The above code can be implemented in many of the script languages existing on your system. Choose any you are comfortable with.

Comment: but that also generates the physical files, or not?

Comment: @yemino: See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple, you can write script in perl or tcl. Below is tcl example.

```
set fp [open "somefile" r]
set file_data [read $fp]
close $fp

set data [split $file_data "\n"]
foreach line $data {
     # do some line processing here
}
```

In this example somefile is a filename and contents are copied into variable file_data.

For more information http://wiki.tcl.tk/367

Comment: Your answer does not fit the question (anymore). But you are right, the code for "for each *.poly ; do triangle file ; execute fortranprogram generated_files; done" could be written in tcl. And I for one would like to see an implementation of it in tcl. Been a while since I saw tcl.